# add include directories to netbeans on mac

Tags: macos, netbeans

Once I installed Netbeans, It worked perfectly but probably after updating to Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.2, netbeans lost include directory path. as shown [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaQ8b.png) and [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rCN5.png). The Central problem is that netbeans cannot find include file as shown [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRUkS.png), and I don't have any ideas how to add the desired path.

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved via simply writing

```
xcode-select --install
```

in terminal